# WP 8.1 code to retrieve pincode from sms

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

I'm developing a message application for Windows Phone 8.1 (RT) that sends messages over wifi and mobile data, and i'm curious if it's possible to retrieve a pin code received by SMS inside the application itself. I've done my research but was unable to find any examples of people who has achieved this.

I wish to be able to do this of security reasons, so that the application itself can catch up the SMS with the pincode, so the verification process is without the user performing the pin code input. If this isn't possible i'd still be glad to confirm this.

Comment: If you can get access from the mobile network operators it looks possible. You can get the message body of the sms, then you should be able to parse the body to extract the pin. https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br206550

Comment: @Barnstokkr The api is not available for regular developers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, it is not possible for a third party app to intercept an SMS to read its contents in Windows Phone. The only alternative is to make the user input the pin manually. But this would still won't be able to detect instances where the user can receive the SMS in a different phone and enter the PIN in your app.